# ComboBox items with checkboxes, bound to the same list of items with different check boxes checked

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in a more MVVMy way and can't figure out how this should be accomplished.

I have a list of groups and a list of databases. For each group I want to show a combo box below it with all of the databases, and I want the databases to be checked if they are available to the specific group. What I can't figure out is how to tell the database list which group it is connected to with some sort of binding.

I have three static lists of objects.
A group, with a name and ID
A database, with a name and ID
A XREF, with a group id, and an object Id

My Group Control looks like the following;

```
<UserControl x:Class="Support.Controls.GroupEdit"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Support.Controls"
             xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:Support.Classes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="200" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=classes:Group}" DataContextChanged="UserControl_DataContextChanged">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <classes:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Text="Name:" />
    <TextBox FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" />
    <local:DatabaseList DataContext="{Binding}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2" x:Name="Databases" />
    <Button Click="Remove_Click"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="Remove" ToolTip="Delete database" Visibility="{Binding Path=CanDelete, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <Image Height="24" Margin="2" Name="AddNewImage" Source="../Images/Remove.png" />
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Database selector control looks like the following;

```
<ComboBox x:Class="Support.Controls.DatabaseList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
             xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:Support.Classes" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Support.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=classes:Group}"
             DataContextChanged="ComboBox_DataContextChanged" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="dbs" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static classes:CachedData.Databases}, Path=DatabaseList}">
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"  Direction="Ascending"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <controls:DatabaseListItem DataContext="{Binding}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Selected Databases (0)" Name="SelectedDatabasesHeader" />
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource dbs}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Lastly, my database control looks like the following;

```
<ComboBoxItem x:Class="PostAuditSupport.Controls.DatabaseListItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:classes="clr-namespace:PostAuditSupport.Classes"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=classes:Database}"
             Selected="ComboBoxItem_Selected" x:Name="DatabaseComboBox">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" Name="Check" Unchecked="Check_Unchecked" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Name="DatabaseName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

Comment: Looks like you have some static classes here that need getting rid. With MvvM you don't need these custom controls. Your Database selector is nothing more than a combo box. That should get it's information from a view model. your database control is nothing more than a combo box item, it's data context should be in an ObservableCollection in your view model, also it should be a data template rather than custom control. Comment section is not enough to describe what to do.

Comment: Thank you, fair enough.  
I'm slowly trying to convert more stuff over to binding, but I was afraid that this might take a major rewrite of the structure of the program.

Comment: Instead of doing it all at once, you could start doing this in steps. Not using custom controls would be a good start. Instead of creating a view model start separating these issues in code behind and use binding to access those. But one step at a time and you'll get there.